# How to refresh device list when Xcode 9 automatically managed the provisional profile

Tags: provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning, xcode9, xcode9-beta

I added a couple of new device via Apple developer portal and still, my Xcode 9 show the profile linked with older device count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Alternative**

1. Just Enable and disable the Automatic Provisioning profile from the General tab of XCode project target selected
2. Go to terminal and navigate to profile directory and delete all profiles and download and install again.

> ```
> $cd ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/
> $rm -r *
> ```

*Note: Make sure you have all the P12 files already for the certs used by the new profiles. Else you will have code signing error.*